# Injected script couldn't be run in all the visited web pages in the WebView react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-web

This injected script was only run in the first page I visited in the web view but my intention was to run it in all the pages that will be visited.
`

```
render() { 
    let jsCode ='alert("test alert")';
    let uri='http://........';
     return (`enter code here`
    <WebView
     source={{uri: uri}}
     injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
     />
     )
    }
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like this might be an issue similar to [what another user was encountering with request headers](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/07/26/passing-request-headers-on-each-webview-request-in-react-native.html). The solution was to essentially trigger a re-render on each page load so that the headers would be included for each of the subsequent pages. You may want to try that here to get the injected Javascript to work on the additional pages.